# how to login a javascript based site with a windows form?

Tags: c#, javascript

I've been trying to login to a site using a WebBrowser control automatically by using the `GetElementByTag` / `GetElemenByName` methods but with not much success. (WFA - C#)

I believe the main reason is the fact that the site is in JavaScript.

I've done some research and found two methods:

1. by mimicking the site login form I could use something called POST. (or something of that sort)
2. inject a javascript input to all the input fields in the site

I have no idea how to approach this problem, and due to my total lack of experience with javaScript or any web based programing, I could realy use any advice or solution for the matter at hand.

/** EDIT 1
thank you for your quick response.
ive tried to use your code and still facing the same exception throw..

here is the code :
(I trimmed it a bit)

```
   public WorkerClass(string url)
    {
     webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
     webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
     webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("c_Username").InnerText = "?????";
     webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("c_Password").InnerText = "?????";
    }
```

and I get a "System.NullReferenceExeption" on the username line above.

the site im trying to access is - "http://www.gool.co.il"...maybe my approach is wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use web browser control ,just find element id on your target page and fill them.

I write a simple one for you:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //navigate to you destination 
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.certiport.com/portal/SSL/Login.aspx");
        }
        bool is_sec_page = false;
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!is_sec_page)
            {
                //get page element with id
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("c_Username").InnerText = "username";
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("c_Password").InnerText = "pass";
                //login in to account(fire a login button promagatelly)
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("c_LoginBtn_c_CommandBtn").InvokeMember("click");
                is_sec_page = true;
            }
            //secound page(if correctly aotanticate
            else
            {
                //intract with sec page elements with theire ids
            }

        }
```